# Where to look for specification about GDTR & IDTR registers?

Tags: x86

I have referred "Intel Architecture Software Developer’s Manual -Volume 1:Basic Architecture" they are NOT specified about GDTR register.

GDTR & IDTR are system registers ? then why Intel manual does not specified about these registers in detail ?

Where to look for more details about these registers.

Answer (score 1):

See [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual
Volume 3B:
System Programming Guide, Part 2](http://www.intel.com/Assets/ja_JP/PDF/manual/253669.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

They are described in the volume 3A, chapter 3 (Protected-Mode Memory Management) and 6 (Interrupt and Exception Handling).

You can download the PDF at this address: [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3A:
System Programming Guide, Part 1](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/253668.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can download a intel 80386 programmer's reference manual, just find GDTR keyword, you will find what you need!